# Dealing with very large sas7bdat (>300GB) files with R

Tags: r, sas, bigdata

I have been searching for a solution to this problem without making any progress. I am looking for a way to deal with (manipulate, filter, etc) sas7bdat files using R without the need to load them to memory because they are so big. I tried spark.sas7bdat, but the package has some issues with the current version of Spark. Is there a way to solve this problem?

I hope there is a way to deal with multiple sas7bdat as if they are sqlite or SQL database that I can access and interact with using R without the need to load the whole data on RAM

Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to SAS?  If so, perhaps you can export your sas7bdat files into csv which would be much more nimble to get into R.

Comment: Maybe https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/

Comment: Also, if you use SAS Universal Viewer, you can export as CSV.

Comment: Is it possible to reshape these before you try and load them?  I work with SAS and often find that the issue is that people use overly "wide" datasets that aren't at the right level, and since SAS allocates space for every possible value (even if it's not filled in) that leaves 300GB datasets when there's only a few hundred MB of real data in there.

Comment: If you know the records layout and only new select columns, you can use the col_select argument in haven::read_sas

Comment: If you can save as CSV, you could use `duckdb::duckdb_read_csv` to work with the data without loading it into memory. More here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LvTX1ZAZy6M

Comment: I don't think there enough information to answer this thoughtfully, which is why there are so many different shots at it. Are there multiple files that together equal ~ 300GB? Do you have the ability process this on a remote cluster? Are you able to config. Spark and chose a release works with spark.sas7bdat? Can you even work with this size of data in SAS currently? Where is this currently stored? A bit more detail would go a long way here.

Comment: @JonSpring Your answer was really helpful for me. Could you put it as an answer so I can choose it as the best answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice new (as of 2020-22) user friendly option for working with larger-than-memory data in R is the `duckdb` package, which is a columnar-vectorized query execution engine designed for analytical queries.

It includes a function `duckdb::duckdb_read_csv` which efficiently loads CSV data into the `duckdb` engine without loading it into R, enabling fast operations on larger-than-memory data.

https://jthomasmock.github.io/bigger-data