# Read large CSV in chunks and transform to RDS in R

Tags: r, csv, large-data

I have a 20GB CSV file that I want to convert to an RDS file in R. However, the original file is too large to be processed (the computer with 64GB RAM tells me that 80.9GB needs to be allocated which exceeds its memory capacity). Therefore I am wondering, whether and how I can read that CSV in chunks, turn each chunk into a separate RDS file and afterward merge them together? Would that yield the same outcome as if I directly turned that one CSV file into an RDS file?

I am very new to R and could unfortunately not find any answers to my question.

Below is the current code I'm using.

```
library(Matrix)
library(data.table)

b <- fread('dtm.csv')
b_matx<- as.matrix(b)
dtm_b <- Matrix(b_matx, sparse = TRUE)

saveRDS(dtm_b, "dtm.rds")
```

Comment: I'm afraid this won't work either. The computer will still need to allocate more memory. However, take a look at the [bigmemory](https://cran.r-project.org/package=bigmemory) package. Also, the question is: do you really need all the data in the CSV? Maybe you can read line by line (or in chunks, as suggested), and then keep only the part that you need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll take a look at it. And yes, I do need all the data.

Comment: Then maybe you want to make some calculations with the data? If yes, then potentially you could calculate the interesting statistics on the fly or in chunks. All summary stats can be calculated like this. How about you tell us something about the data?

Comment: If it's so big, your best bet is an actual relational database engine. There are plenty of free options that are pretty easy to use, e.g. SQLite, MariaDB/MySQL, PostgreSQL. The R package `DBI` allows you to access these databases from R directly and you can even use dplyr syntax with the package `dbplyr`

Comment: @January The data is a document-term matrix (120.000 trigrams over 90.000 documents) and I need to convert it to RDS to run an algorithm from [this paper](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3630898) in R on the entire data to obtain a filtered matrix. Therefore I, unfortunately, can't omit parts of the data.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck That's what I did but at some point, this error pops up.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Good point, that's what I just tried and that's the error I get `pyarrow.lib.ArrowMemoryError: malloc of size 730560 failed`.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/73187941/6851825 
  and   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60928866/read-a-20gb-file-in-chunks-without-exceeding-my-ram-r

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Yes, I did, similar error

Answer (score 0):

See if this works.

It reads one column at a time using `fread`.  By default `fread` creates a data frame; however, these use external pointers which can be
problem so we use `data.table=FALSE` argument. After reading a columni n it immediately writes it back out as an RDS file.  After all columns have been written back out as RDS files it reads the RDS files back in and writes the final RDS file out which combines them.  We use the 6 row input in the Note at the end as an example.

If `fread` with `select=` still takes up too much memory use the xsv utility (not an R program) to ensure that only the column of interest is read in.  xsv can be downloaded for various platforms [here](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv/releases/tag/0.13.0) and then use the commented out line instead of the line following it.  (Alternately suitably use `cut`, `sed` or `awk` for the same purpose.)

You can also try interspersing the code lines with `gc()` to trigger garbage collection.

Also try replacing `as.data.frame` in the last line with `setDT`.

```
library(data.table)

File <- "BOD.csv"

freadDF <- function(..., data.table = FALSE) fread(..., data.table = data.table)
L <- as.list(freadDF(File, nrows = 0))
nms <- names(L)
fmt <- "xsv select %s %s"
# for(nm in nms) saveRDS(freadDF(cmd = sprintf(fmt, nm, File))[[1]], paste0(nm, ".rds"))
for(nm in nms) saveRDS(freadDF(File, select = nm)[[1]],  paste0(nm, ".rds"))

for(nm in names(L)) L[[nm]] <- readRDS(paste0(nm, ".rds"))
saveRDS(as.data.frame(L), sub(".csv$", ".rds", File))
```

### Note

```
write.csv(BOD, "BOD.csv", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```